# Robotium - Is it possible for Robotium to open another application from the application under the test

Tags: android, robotium

My question is as follows :- I have an android app that i have been able to automate w/o the source code, However, I have a concern, My app has the functionality of sending email and also visit the the website and i am unable to automate that. I wanted to know whether it is possible? Is it possible to open another app from the app under test?

To send email i have other apps installed on my device, is it possible to trigger them using the application under test.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't go out from the AUT but you can lunch in sequence another test for the application that is launched from your AUT.

This is taken from Question And Answer page of Robotium:

No, that is not possible. In the AndroidManifest.xml you state which target application you want to test. An example of what it can look like:

```
<instrumentation android:targetPackage="com.example.android.notepad" android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner" />
```

That means that the test project is locked to the targetPackage. Going outside of that target package is not allowed by the Android platform. Therefore you will need 2 test projects, one for each application.